# Firebug not showing the response from jquery form plugin post submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am usinh jquery form plugin with this code

```
$(".form1").live('submit', function(e){   

 $(".form1").ajaxSubmit(options); 
});
```

Now i see that firebug console shows all ajax requests so that i can see the request and response.

But i have seen that when i use the above code then my ajax request is completed but i can't see any post request in console.

But if i use

```
$(".form1").live('submit', function(e){   

 var queryString = $('.form1').formSerialize(); 
  $.post('/book/create/', queryString);
```

Then i can see the request response

i want to know why is that

Comment: Only ajax requests (XMLHttpRequest) are shown in the console. Use the net panel to debug all other requests.

Comment: But is the `ajaxSubmit` is not the ajax request??

Comment: I don't know how that plugin works ..  

Comment: wow buddy that net panel is excellent , can u put that in answer , it was great info

Comment: I have put answer see that too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only ajax requests (XMLHttpRequest) are shown in the console. Use the net panel to debug all other requests.

But [`.ajaxSubmit()`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) is indeed an ajax request as the docs say

> ajaxSubmit
>
> Immediately submits the form via AJAX.
>   In the most common use case this is
>   invoked in response to the user
>   clicking a submit button on the form.
>   ajaxSubmit takes zero or one argument.
>   The single argument can be either a
>   callback function or an Options
>   Object.

The problem may be that you're not preventing the actual form submission in your code .

```
$(".form1").live('submit', function(e){   
   $(".form1").ajaxSubmit(options); 
   return false; // this will prevent the actual form submission.
});
```

Comment: i have that line in the ends , but console is not showing that but i can see all in NET panel. thanks for that